# $6$ real numbers, sum of any $3$ consecutive is negative, while sum of any $4$ consecutive is positive. Prove false.

Tags: combinatorics

It's from my combinatorics class, could anyone give me some hints? Thanks

Sorry, I shortened the original phrasing of the question, which made it ambiguous here. The question goes:

A computer programmer claims that he generated six real numbers $a_1, a_2... a_6$ so that the sum of any four consecutive $a_i$ is positive, but the sum of any three consecutive $a_i$ is negative. Prove that his claim is false.
I wonder how to work on this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the simulataneous inequalties
 $$a + b + c + d > 0,$$
 $$a + b + c < 0,$$
 $$b + c + d < 0.$$

What can we say about the sign of $a$?
What about the sign of $d$?

If you have a sequence of six numbers, it has three subsequences each consisting of
four consecutive numbers. Consider what each of them tells you about
numbers in the original sequence.

Comment: Oh, so here I got a>0, d>0, and similarly, b>0, c>0 which makes a+b+c>0, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

$0>(a+b+c)+(b+c+d)+(c+d+e)+(d+e+f)=a+2 b +3 c +3 d +2 e+f.$
$0<(a+b+c+d)+(b+c+d+e)+(c+d+e+f)=a+2 b+3 c+3 d+2 e +f.$

Comment: I suppose it was a claim by a computer programmer who made the claim because he told his computer to do the calculations on a set of 6 values and didn't  de-bug his code.